# Sync multiple coundowns o diferent devices react native

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, momentjs

Hi I'm using React Native to create an Auctions App I have a Flat List for render each product in auction. On the Flat List component I've a interval of 1000 milliseconds for update the state on all the items the time left.

And for update the current time I use the following method:

```js
updateTime(){
let currentTime = moment().unix();
let diffTime = this.state.product.endTime - currentTime;
let duration = moment.duration(diffTime * 1000, 'milliseconds');
          
return duration.hours() + ":" + duration.minutes() + ":" + duration.seconds();
}
```

I retrive the end time for each product from Firebase Firestore.

But for some reason that I do not understand, the time remaining in different devices varies between 2, 3 or even 4 seconds.

If you can tell me what I am doing wrong or what is the best way to do this, I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`moment()` gets the time set on the device, so it's expected that your different devices are not set to the exact same time.

You can use a time elapsed interval instead to count down after fetching the product end time:

```
setInterval(() => this.setState(prevState => ({ timeElapsed: prevState.timeElapsed + 1 }), 1000);
...
const timeRemaining = this.state.product.endTime - this.state.timeElapsed
```

Comment: Then you just multiply `timeElapsed` by 1000 or `+ 1000` instead.